# Erro na resposta do ajax para PHP

Tags: php

Supostamente estou a fazer o pedido para aceder à página *registo.php* o que deveria fazer o código e passar se o registo foi bem feito ou não , ams ao invés ele simplesmente copia para o alert, no sucess, o código de php na integra, não pecebo porquê, alguém me pode ajudar ??

javascript :

```
function submeterRegisto(){
$.ajax({
    url: "registo.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:   $('tabelareg').serialize(),
    dataType:'HTML', 
    success: function (response) {                 
    alert("sucesso: "+ response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

PHP:(exemplo)

> registo.php

```
 <?
    if($_POST['confpass'] == $_POST['pass']){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $nome=$_POST['name'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];

        echo"registo completo (teste)";
    }else
        echo"não compelto (teste)";
  ?>
```

Quando efetuo o submit no site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em **registo.php** altere **<?** para **<?php**

Comment: Você consegue acessar uma pagina .php normalmente no mesmo nível de pastas do registro.php? Pois esse tipo de comportamento e falha na connfiguração do servidor PHP.

Comment: Realmente ao alterar de <? para <?php ele já funcionou corretamente , muito obrigado